# RegExp set contains one or multiple words

Tags: regex, set, subset

Is there a way in regular expressions to match a **subset** of words against a **set** of words separated by a separator that does not involve creating a new pattern for every new word added to the set.

Right now I cannot think of anything else than creating a (?:{*item1*, *item2*, ...}) pattern for every extra *item* in the set (see example below).

Example matching a **single** word of the set:

```
Set: foo,bar,baz
Match: foo
RegExp:/^(foo|bar|baz)$/ <- MATCH
```

Example that will match a **subset** of words:

```
Set: foo,bar,baz
Match: foo,bar
RegExp: /^(foo|bar|baz)(?:,(foo|bar|baz)(?:,(foo|bar|baz))?)?$/ <- MATCH
```

The pattern grows rapidly when adding new items to the set. Is there some (magical) way to do this in a shorter version?

Answer (score 0):

One general approach which looks slightly better than your current attempt would be to use lookaheads:

```regex
^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b).*$
```

### Demo

You may add one lookahead assertion for each CSV term which needs to be matched in the input CSV list.

**Edit:** If you want OR behavior here, then we can use an alternation of lookaheads.  To match either `foo` or `bar` as a CSV term we can try:

```regex
^(?:(?=.*\bfoo\b)|(?=.*\bbar\b)).*$
```

Comment: I have considered using lookaheads too. You would need an OR operator to make it match one or multiple while also taking into account the separator. This RegExp now does not match a single value e.g. foo.

Comment: I assumed you wanted AND logic.  Yes, you may use an alternation `|` of lookaheads for OR.

Comment: The pattern would then look something like (but does not include any characters in the match): ^(?=.*\bfoo\b)|(?=.*\bbar\b)|(?=\b.*baz\b).*$. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase; if you agree the pattern provided by me equals your idea of adding the OR logic as you suggested. It now matches a single 'foo' value but the match does not contain any characters. That still remains to be solved.